# Is it correct to say "She behaves" or "She behaves herself"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

According to the Oxford dictionary

> [behave](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/behave?q=behave) [intransitive, transitive] to do things in a way that people
> think is correct or polite
>
> Will you kids just behave!
>
> She doesn't know how to behave in public.
>
> The children always behave for their father.
>
> **behave yourself** I want you to behave yourselves while I'm away.

---

My idea is that

If we treated language like math, could we say?

-"**She behaves**"

because if we replace the verb "**behave**" with "**to do things in a way that people think is correct or polite**", the sentence will be

-"**She does things in a way that people think is correct or polite**".

However, "**she behaves**" doesn't make much sense and like examples in the dictionary, we need to add more words, for example,

"**She knows how to behave**" or "**She behaves well**" or something like that.

Is it correct to say "**She behaves**" or "**She behaves herself**"?

Comment: You are right that **She behaves** doesn't mean very much because, as you see from the dictionary, **behave** also means 'act in a particular way'. You need additional words to make it clear that you mean it in the sense 'behaves well'.

Comment: "'She behaves' doesn't make much sense and ... we need to add more words... " Do we? "Oh behave!"

Comment: (In other words, I move that "She behaves" isn't grammatically invalid but simply unclear. No, strike that, I think it's perfectly clear. An intransitive use of *behave* implies *good* behavior. Imagine: "Your dog attacked me!" "Yeah, she behaves." "What are you talking about, her behavior is horrible!" "Ah, she behaves *badly*. You'll note I didn't say *how* she behaves." "Okay, I get it; you're a bigger jerk than your dog."

Comment: Grammar and semantics aside, I can't see where you'd ever want to use this phrase - unless you were talking about a dog.  To my ear, *behave* does not mean *comport oneself correctly*, but means *act obediently*.  Some strict parents may demand obedience from their children, but this attitude is now (at least in the US) unpopular enough that telling someone else that your daughter is "well-behaved" would sound old-fashioned at best.

Comment: It's hard to see any context where a native speaker might make the bald assertion ***She behaves***. But it's perfectly okay to use ***to behave*** "non-reflexively" in contexts like *If your toddler behaves, she will be given a lollipop* (where reflexive *...behaves **herself*** is also perfectly valid, and means exactly the same).

Comment: @Juhasz I disagree; a non-transitive use of *behave* [does](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behave) in fact mean "comport oneself correctly." Correct comportment may of course obey orders, but such a connotation is not required; I would argue that "well-behaved" is broader than "obedient." And, although it might not be the most original or helpful compliment, I don't see that calling a child "well-behaved" implies a Draconian parenting paradigm or is received as old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *'behave'* is an *ambitransitive* verb (used both transitively & intransitively) :

> Used as a transitive reflexive verb : **She behaves herself**.

Here, the verb *'behaves‘* is a transitive reflexive verb taking the reflextive object *‘herself‘*. Here the verb *‘behave‘* means *‘to act in a polite or proper way‘*. So, the sentence means *‘She behaves politely or properly‘*·

> Used as an intransitive verb : **She behaves well / like a child.**

When the verb *‘behave‘* is used intransitively (non-reflexively), it means *‘to act in a particular way‘. To indicate that *particular way*, we use *adverb/ adverbial phrase* :

She behaves *well*. (well > adverb)

She behaves *like a child* (like a child > adverbial phrase)

Even an intransitive verb *‘behave‘*  also means *‘to act politely or properly*‘ : *"Mother is always telling me to behave when we go out"*.

Therefore, **"She behaves"** is correct; but you can add an adverb or adverbial phrase or an reflexive object for the clarity of the sentence.